# Lucene: Prefix token-wise match OR prefix of exact match

Tags: java, lucene

I have a few thousand strings that look something like this

- Foo-Bar-Herp
- Foo-Bar-Derp
- Baz-Blurb Something else

I'm want to provide a search that works so that

- "foo bar"   (tokenized prefix)
- "foo herp"  (skips a token)
- "foo-bar-"  (exact prefix)
- "Bar-Herp"  (exact string in the middle)
- "foo ba"    (one whole token and prefix of another token)

etc. 
All return the first string (and possibly others), but

- "herp foo" (wrong order, not critical)
- "foo blerp" (not all tokens)
- "murp herp" (not all tokens)

do not.

I.e. both exact prefix match and token (potentially prefix) matches in the right order should match, independent of case, but all tokens in the query must be in the document.

I've set up the typical Lucene example using a StandardAnalyzer and a common QueryParser with a prefix query.

I figure I might need a BinaryQuery to state that I need all tokens in the query to be in the documents but I can't quite figure to get at the tokens to build it (The query is user-supplied). I also realize that using a StringField instead of a TextField gives me the exact string matches as opposed to the token-wise matches, but I'm not sure if that's something I can combine with the above?

How should I go about this? I don't even have to use Lucene to do it, but it looked like a good fit.

Comment: You say that "foo herp" should return results but "foo derp" shouldn't - providing you have Foo-Bar-Herp and Foo-Bar-Derp. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I just meant it shouldn't return the first result. It *should* return the second result. Changing the example.

Answer (score 1):

Your first one (non-critical) is a little trickier, but to make sure all terms in the query are found in all results, you can simply make all of the query terms required.  You can do this with either added plus operators:

- `+foo +bar`
- `+foo +ba*` (if you want to handle prefixes, you'll need to add the wildcards to specify it, or possibly use an ngram tokenizer, or some such)
- etc.

Or, you can just set the default operator to be `AND`, using [`StandardQueryParser.setDefaultOperator`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/StandardQueryParser.html#setDefaultOperator(org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.config.StandardQueryConfigHandler.Operator))

```
queryParser.setDefaultOperator(StandardQueryConfigHandler.Operator.AND);
```

---

In the case of `herp foo` vs `foo herp`, phrase slop will probably, I think, get you where you need to be.  Swapping the order of terms will add two to the distance, so:

- `"foo herp"~2`: matches "Foo-Bar-Herp"
- `"herp foo"~2`: does not

Phrase queries do not support wildcards though, so if you need to combine this with prefix terms, you'll run into problems.

If you want to allow more slop than that without the order being changed, then I believe you are moving outside the ability of the `QueryParser` to express your query, and will need to go to the `SpanQuery` API to construct your queries manually.

Constructing queries manually, you could do something like:

```
SpanQuery term1 = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("content", "foo"));
SpanQuery term2Prefix = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new PrefixQuery(new Term("content", "her")));
SpanQuery finalQuery = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {term1, term2Prefix}, 5, true);
```

Which looks for the the first term (exact match) and a prefix of the second term, in order, with no more than five terms between them.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot. I don't care as much about the ordering thing, but I do care about "foo-bar-" (exact prefix) working, and it currently doesn't. Does the tokenization work differently on indexing and search, even with the same Analyzer? Are the dashes considered minus operators?